# How to write test class? Urgent

Tags: apex, class, salesforce-classic

public with sharing class MFG_BSAPP_RPT_ROUTELIST_CTRL {
    public String g_userId {set; get;}
    public String g_userName {set; get;}
    public String g_userLocationId {set; get;}
    public String g_userRole {set; get;}

```
//report content
public List<String> reportContentList {set;
    get {
        if (reportContentList==null) {
            reportContentList = new List<String>();
        }
        return reportContentList;
    }    
}

//nested list
public List<List<String>> reportContentListX {set;
    get {
        if (reportContentListX==null) {
            reportContentListX = new List<List<String>>();
        }
        return reportContentListX;
    }
}


public MFG_BSAPP_RPT_ROUTELIST_CTRL() {
     //retrieve cookies
    Cookie cookieItem;
    cookieItem= ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('bsckUserId');
    if (cookieItem != null) {
        g_userId = cookieItem.getValue();
    }

    cookieItem= ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('bsckUserName');
    if (cookieItem != null) {
        g_userName = cookieItem.getValue();
    }

    cookieItem= ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('bsckSelectedLocId');
    if (cookieItem != null) {
        g_userLocationId = cookieItem.getValue();
    }

    cookieItem= ApexPages.currentPage().getCookies().get('bsckSelectedRoleName');
    if (cookieItem != null) {
        g_userRole = cookieItem.getValue();
    } 
}

//access validation method
public PageReference accessValidation() {

    MFG_BSAPP_LOCATION__c locationObj = [SELECT id, NAME__c, SITE_ID__r.NAME__c
                                            FROM MFG_BSAPP_LOCATION__c
                                            WHERE ACTIVE_FLAG__c = true 
                                             AND id=:g_userLocationId];

    String locName = 'Location: ' + locationObj.NAME__c;
    String siteName = 'Site: ' + locationObj.SITE_ID__r.NAME__c;
    String dateString = 'Date: ' + MFG_BSAPP_UTIL_CLS.convertDate2String(Date.today());

     //add report name
    reportContentList.add( locationObj.SITE_ID__r.NAME__c + ' Bus Route Listing Report');

    //add site, location, date info in a line
    String sldString = siteName + ',' + locName.escapeCsv() + ',' + dateString;
    reportContentList.add(sldString);
    String line = '';

    List<MFG_BSAPP_ROUTE_MASTER__c> RouteList = [SELECT id,ROUTE__c FROM MFG_BSAPP_ROUTE_MASTER__c WHERE LOCATION_ID__c = :g_userLocationId and id in (SELECT ROUTE_ID__c FROM MFG_BSAPP_CODE_MASTER__c
                                                     WHERE LOCATION_ID__c = :g_userLocationId) ORDER BY ROUTE__c];

     for (Integer j=0;j<RouteList.size();j++) {
            MFG_BSAPP_ROUTE_MASTER__c RouteObj = RouteList[j];   
            reportContentList.add('Bus Route:  ' + RouteObj.ROUTE__c);

       List <MFG_BSAPP_CODE_DETAIL__c> CodeList = [SELECT ROUTE_ID__r.Route__c,SHIFT_ID__r.DESCRIPTION__c,TIME1__c,TIME2__c,TIME3__c,STOP_ID__r.STOP_CODE__c,STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION1__c,STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION2__c FROM MFG_BSAPP_CODE_DETAIL__c WHERE LOCATION_ID__c = :g_userLocationId AND ROUTE_ID__c = :RouteObj.id ORDER BY ROUTE_ID__r.Route__c,SHIFT_ID__r.DESCRIPTION__c,TIME1__c,TIME2__c,TIME3__c];                        
            reportContentList.add('Bus Shift,Stop Time1,Stop Time2,Stop Time3,Stop Code,Stop Description'); 
       for (Integer i=0; i<CodeList.size(); i++) {
            if (reportContentList.size() < 1000) {
                MFG_BSAPP_CODE_DETAIL__c CodeObj = CodeList[i];

                if (CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION2__c == null) {
                CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION2__c = '';
                }

                if (CodeObj.TIME2__c == null) {
                CodeObj.TIME2__c = '';
                }

                if (CodeObj.TIME3__c == null) {
                CodeObj.TIME3__c = '';
                }   

                line = CodeObj.SHIFT_ID__r.DESCRIPTION__c + ',' +  CodeObj.TIME1__c +','+ CodeObj.TIME2__c +','+ CodeObj.TIME3__c +',' + CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.STOP_CODE__c +','+ CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION1__c +'/'+ CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION2__c;
                reportContentList.add(line);
                line = '';

            } else {
                reportContentListX.add(reportContentList);
                reportContentList = new List<String>();

                MFG_BSAPP_CODE_DETAIL__c CodeObj = CodeList[i];

                if (CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION2__c == null) {
                CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION2__c = '';
                }

                if (CodeObj.TIME2__c == null) {
                CodeObj.TIME2__c = '';
                }

                if (CodeObj.TIME3__c == null) {
                CodeObj.TIME3__c = '';
                }   

                line = CodeObj.SHIFT_ID__r.DESCRIPTION__c + ',' +  CodeObj.TIME1__c +','+ CodeObj.TIME2__c +',' + CodeObj.TIME3__c +',' + CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.STOP_CODE__c +','+ CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION1__c +'/'+ CodeObj.STOP_ID__r.DESCRIPTION2__c;
                reportContentList.add(line);
                line = '';
            }                                              
        }
       }
        reportContentListX.add(reportContentList);

    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you tried writing a test class first? Please post the code here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a test class:

```
@isTest
public class UrgentTestClass{
}
```